# Angular Router components are stacking

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular-router

Just started working with react router and I'm running into a problem. I have contact and menu components that act as different pages in the website. When I click contact, I get the following:

[image]

If I click menu, I get the following:

[image]

It seems as though, the position of the contact component is somehow affecting the positioning of the menu component. Is there something I'm missing about how react router works?

main-window.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-window',
    templateUrl: 'main-window.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['main-window.component.css']
})

export class MainWindowComponent {

}
```

main-window.component.html

```
<header></header>
<div class="main-window-style">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

menu.component.html

```
<div>This is the Menu Page</div>
```

contact.component.html

```
<div>This is the Contact Page</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // CLI imports router
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainWindowComponent } from './main-window/main-window.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainWindowComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

main-window.component.css

```
.main-window-style {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0.50turn, #3A7D44, #C90F0F);
}
```

Is there some setting that I need to disable from the router to get it to function properly? Also, let me know if there's any other files you need to see.

Comment: Is there any component specific style in menu component? What does your css/scss files say?

Comment: There aren't any css files for menu or contact. I'll most what I have for the main-window css file.

Comment: Can you put your code in a StackBlitz? I guess that the **This is the menu page** element has a `margin-top`. Inspect the label with Developer tools (F12)